# Synchronous and blocking consumption in RabbitMQ using pika

Tags: python, python-2.7, rabbitmq, pika

I want to consume a queue (RabbitMQ) synchronously with blocking.

**Note: below is full code ready to be run.**

The system set up is using RabbitMQ as it's queuing system, but asynchronous consumption is not needed in one of our modules.

I've tried using basic_get on top of a [BlockingConnection](http://pika.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/adapters/blocking.html), which doesn't block (returns `(None, None, None)` immediately):

```
# declare queue
get_connection().channel().queue_declare(TEST_QUEUE)
def blocking_get_1():

        channel = get_connection().channel()

        # get from an empty queue (prints immediately)
        print channel.basic_get(TEST_QUEUE)
```

I've also tried to use the [consume generator](http://pika.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples/blocking_consumer_generator.html), fails with "Connection Closed" after a long time of not consuming.

```
def blocking_get_2():
        channel = get_connection().channel()
        # put messages in TEST_QUEUE
        for i in range(4):
                channel.basic_publish(
                        '',
                        TEST_QUEUE,
                        'body %d' % i
                )
        consume_generator = channel.consume(TEST_QUEUE)
        print next(consume_generator)
        time.sleep(14400)
        print next(consume_generator)
```

Is there a way to use RabbitMQ using the pika client as I would a `Queue.Queue` in python? or anything similar?

My option at the moment is busy-wait (using basic_get) - but I rather use the existing system to not busy-wait, if possible.

Full code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika
import time

TEST_QUEUE = 'test'
def get_connection():
        # define connection
        connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
                pika.ConnectionParameters(
                        host=YOUR_IP,
                        port=YOUR_PORT,
                        credentials=pika.PlainCredentials(
                                username=YOUR_USER,
                                password=YOUR_PASSWORD,
                        )
                )
        )
        return connection

# declare queue
get_connection().channel().queue_declare(TEST_QUEUE)
def blocking_get_1():

        channel = get_connection().channel()

        # get from an empty queue (prints immediately)
        print channel.basic_get(TEST_QUEUE)

def blocking_get_2():
        channel = get_connection().channel()
        # put messages in TEST_QUEUE
        for i in range(4):
                channel.basic_publish(
                        '',
                        TEST_QUEUE,
                        'body %d' % i
                )
        consume_generator = channel.consume(TEST_QUEUE)
        print next(consume_generator)
        time.sleep(14400)
        print next(consume_generator)


print "blocking_get_1"
blocking_get_1()

print "blocking_get_2"
blocking_get_2()

get_connection().channel().queue_delete(TEST_QUEUE)
```

Comment: I think it also has to do with not sending the heartbeat (`consume` possibly blocks them?) as seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14572020/handling-long-running-tasks-in-pika-rabbitmq

Comment: I posted my take on this, but let me know if I misunderstood your question. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A common problem with Pika is that it is currently not handling incoming events in the background. This basically means that in many scenarios you will need to call `connection.process_data_events()` periodically to ensure that it does not miss heartbeats.

This also means that if you sleep for a extended period of time, pika will not be handling incoming data, and eventually die as it is not responding to heartbeats. An option here is to disable heartbeats.

I usually solve this by having a thread in the background check for new events, as seen in [this](https://github.com/eandersson/python-rabbitmq-examples/blob/master/Flask-examples/pika_async_rpc_example.py#L68) example.

If you want to block completely I would do something like this (based on my own library [AMQPStorm](https://www.amqpstorm.io/)).

```
while True:
    result = channel.basic.get(queue='simple_queue', no_ack=False)
    if result:
        print("Message:", message.body)
        message.ack()
    else:
        print("Channel Empty.")
        sleep(1)
```

This is based on the example found [here](https://github.com/eandersson/amqpstorm/blob/2.10.4/examples/consume_queue_until_empty.py#L12).

Comment: I remember having trouble when accessing the connection from two threads. Inter-thread communication adds overhead so I'm going to wait for a way to do it without it.

I'll give it another go later on and update here.

Comment: Yea if you are using pika it can be difficult. It is not designed for threading, but the example I linked can handle quite a lot of simultaneous messages. My library amqp-storm on the other hand should make it easier, as it is thread safe.

Comment: the links provided are outdated...