# RabbitMQ how pika.adapters.blocking_connection.BlockingConnection.process_data_events works?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I'm working with python2.7 and pika 0.10.0 and trying to understand how to use `pika.adapters.blocking_connection.BlockingConnection.process_data_events` . From the [doc](http://pika.readthedocs.io/en/0.10.0/modules/adapters/blocking.html#pika.adapters.blocking_connection.BlockingConnection.process_data_events):

> Will make sure that data events are processed. Dispatches timer and
>   channel callbacks if not called from the scope of BlockingConnection
>   or BlockingChannel callback. Your app can block on this method.

If we also look at the parameter:

> Parameters: time_limit (float) – suggested upper bound on processing time in
>   seconds. The actual blocking time depends on the granularity of the
>   underlying ioloop. Zero means return as soon as possible. None means
>   there is no limit on processing time and the function will block until
>   I/O produces actionalable events. Defaults to 0 for backward
>   compatibility. This parameter is NEW in pika 0.10.0.

My understanding is that calling `process_data_events(time_limit=2)` will block for up to 2 seconds, and if in the meanwhile an event occur (e.g. we receive a message on a channel) that event will be processed; if the callback which is called in response to that event takes more than 2 seconds, it will run to completion and `process_data_events(time_limit=2)` **will return, possible after 2 seconds**.

Is the correct behaviour?

Comment: I took a glance at pika source, don't think it has the ability to limit callback execution time.

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46053349/keep-pika-blockingconnection-alive-without-disabling-heartbeat/46866508#46866508)