# Running long tasks with rabbitmq and pika

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I'm using pika to run long tasks. Unfortunately, this ends up running into heartbeat timeout. Unfortunately, prolonging heartbeat periods is not a solution, and i would like to avoid workarounds like using database, etc.

What is a proper solution, to deal with long running tasks and heartbeat, without loosing benefits of RabbitMQ?

Note: I know this question was asked before, but many of the answers are related to previous versions of pika. I would like to know if there is a better solution to this issue.

Comment: If your code is running under Python 3.5+ use asyncio implementation.

Comment: Try this https://github.com/pika/pika/blob/0.12.0/examples/basic_consumer_threaded.py

Comment: I'm experimenting with the AsyncioConnection, but the connection is always closed after creation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52951933/1466825