# Pika heartbeat terminates connection

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I have a code that just enqueuing a message to the broker's queue with pika.

```py
class Publisher:

    def __init__(self, config):
        self._params = ConnectionParameters(
            host = config.RABBITMQ_HOST,
            credentials = PlainCredentials(config.RABBITMQ_USER, config.RABBITMQ_PASSWORD))
        self._conn = None
        self._channel = None
        self.exchange_name = config.RABBITMQ_AGENT_EXCHANGE


    def connect(self):
        if not self._conn or self._conn.is_closed:
            self._conn = BlockingConnection(self._params)
            self._channel = self._conn.channel()
            self._channel.exchange_declare(exchange=self.exchange_name,  exchange_type = 'topic')

    def _publish(self, task):
        properties = BasicProperties(expiration=task.expiration_ms)
        self._channel.basic_publish(exchange= self.exchange_name,
                                    routing_key = task.routing_key,
                                    properties = properties if task.has_expiration else None,
                                    body=dumps(task, cls = TaskEncoder).encode())
        logging.debug('message sent: %s', task)


    def publish(self, msg):
        """Publish msg, reconnecting if necessary."""

        try:
            self._publish(msg)
        except ConnectionClosed:
            logging.error('reconnecting to queue')
            self.connect()
            self._publish(msg)
```

Pika stops enqueuing messages for long-running connection with the next messages and doesn't throw any error anymore

```
2021-03-14 12:25:09,981 MainThread-140100212655936 pika.heartbeat [INFO] - Connection is idle, 1 stale byte intervals
2021-03-14 12:25:09,981 MainThread-140100212655936 pika.adapters.utils.io_services_utils [INFO] - Aborting transport connection: state=1; <socket.socket fd=6, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=6, laddr=('192.168.184.108', 41024), raddr=('10.100.176.158', 5672)>
2021-03-14 12:25:09,981 MainThread-140100212655936 pika.adapters.utils.io_services_utils [INFO] - _AsyncTransportBase._initate_abort(): Initiating abrupt asynchronous transport shutdown: state=1; error=None; <socket.socket fd=6, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=6, laddr=('192.168.184.108', 41024), raddr=('10.100.176.158', 5672)
```

Code usage

```
publisher = Publisher(config)
publisher.connect()
while True:
  publisher.publish(obj)
  time.sleep(1)
```

I have 2 questions:

How to prevent it? Does it disabling heartbeat can work in this case?

How to reproduce/simulate this behavior with a firewall? I tried to add a rule with packet drop on RMQ port but with no luck.

Pika version: 1.0.1

RMQ version: 3.8.9

Python: 3.8.6

Comment: Have you found a solution for this issue?

Comment: @Daniel Nope. Unfortunately, I haven't found the cause.

Answer (score 0):

there are quite a few posts that recommend keeping the callback execution very short, so the control should go back to pika.
[see more on it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14572020/handling-long-running-tasks-in-pika-rabbitmq)

if you have big things to calculate, it's better to span them to another thread/process, or accumulate them for later execution.
this concept helped me with other real-time api.

what seems to happen, is that rabbit is closing the channel (you may catch that in a callback, if your hands aren't busy other place), and the heartbeat seems to me is stopped by pika.

- links

Comment: I think you are missing the point. He is not consuming anything here, just sending messages. That's as fast as rabbitmq and network allow.