# RabbitMQ Pika long-running task and heartbeat threading

Tags: python, rabbitmq, python-multithreading, pika

I have attempted to follow guidance given here: [Handling long running tasks in pika / RabbitMQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14572020/handling-long-running-tasks-in-pika-rabbitmq) and here: https://github.com/pika/pika/issues/753#issuecomment-318124510 on how to run long tasks in a separate thread to avoid interrupting the connection heartbeat. I'm a beginner to threading and still struggling to understand this solution.

For my final use case, I need to make function calls that are several minutes long, represented in the example code below by the long_function(). I've found that if the sleep call in long_function() exceeds the length of the heartbeat timeout, I lose connection (presumably because this function is blocking thread #2 from receiving/acknowledging the heartbeat messages from thread #1) and I get this message in the logs: `ERROR: Unexpected connection close detected: StreamLostError: ("Stream connection lost: RxEndOfFile(-1, 'End of input stream (EOF)')",)`. A sleep call of the same length in the target function of thread #2 does not lead to a StreamLostError.

**What's the proper solution for overcoming the StreamLostError here?** Do I launch all subsequent function calls in their own threads to avoid blocking thread #2? Do I increase the heartbeat to be longer than long_function()? If this is the solution, what was the point of running my long task in a separate thread? Why not just make the heartbeat timeout in the main thread long enough to accommodate the whole message being processed? Thanks!

```
import functools
import logging
import pika
import threading
import time
import os
import ssl
from common_utils.rabbitmq_utils import send_message_to_queue, initialize_rabbitmq_channel
import json
import traceback


logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s',
                    level=logging.INFO,
                    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')


def send_message_to_queue(channel, queue_name, body):
    channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                        routing_key=queue_name,
                        body=json.dumps(body),
                        properties=pika.BasicProperties(delivery_mode=2)
                        )
    logging.info("RabbitMQ publish to queue {} confirmed".format(queue_name))


def initialize_rabbitmq_channel(timeout=5*60):
    credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(os.environ.get("RABBITMQ_USER"), os.environ.get("RABBITMQ_PASSWORD"))
    context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
    params = pika.ConnectionParameters(port=5671, host=os.environ.get("RABBITMQ_HOST"), credentials=credentials,
                                       ssl_options=pika.SSLOptions(context), virtual_host="/", heartbeat=timeout)
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(params)
    return connection.channel(), connection


def long_function():
    logging.info("Long function starting...")
    time.sleep(5)
    logging.info("Long function finished.")


def ack_message(channel, delivery_tag):
    """
    Note that `channel` must be the same pika channel instance via which
    the message being ACKed was retrieved (AMQP protocol constraint).
    """
    if channel.is_open:
        channel.basic_ack(delivery_tag)
        logging.info("Message {} acknowledged".format(delivery_tag))
    else:
        logging.error("Channel is closed and message acknowledgement will fail")
        pass


def do_work(connection, channel, delivery_tag, body):

    thread_id = threading.get_ident()
    fmt1 = 'Thread id: {} Delivery tag: {} Message body: {}'
    logging.info(fmt1.format(thread_id, delivery_tag, body))

    # Simulating work including a call to another function that exceeds heartbeat timeout
    time.sleep(5)
    long_function()

    send_message_to_queue(channel, "test_inactive", json.loads(body))

    cb = functools.partial(ack_message, channel, delivery_tag)
    connection.add_callback_threadsafe(cb)


def on_message(connection, channel, method, property, body):
    t = threading.Thread(target=do_work, args=(connection, channel, method.delivery_tag, body))
    t.start()
    t.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    channel, connection = initialize_rabbitmq_channel(timeout=3)
    channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
    channel.basic_consume(queue="test_queue",
                        auto_ack=False,
                        on_message_callback=lambda channel, method, property, body: on_message(connection, channel, method, property, body)
                        )

    channel.start_consuming()
```

Comment: This looks like reasonable code at first glance. Please open an issue in the Pika GitHub repository. Provide a repo I can clone and run your code from. PS I maintain Pika. Thanks.